# How to broadcast the audio of a web page to an Icecast server?

Tags: audio, web, stream, icecast, liquidsoap

I'd like to broadcast the audio provided by a web page which, in my case, contains YouTube videos synced with all the other people on this page at the same time.
I'd like to do that with a Debian 8 server without any graphical interface or sound card.
First, I thought I could manage that with Liquidsoap but I didn't find any way to deal with it.
I didn't find anyone trying to do the same thing as me while searching on Google.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what specifically you're trying to do?  You want to stream the audio from the YouTube video player to an Icecast server as the source stream?  Or, you want to get audio somehow and play it back synchronized with YouTube videos?  It isn't clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Especially expand on "synced with all the other people on this page at the same time". Use non-technical terms to avoid jumping to conclusions. I want people who do A to be able to hear B, etc. In detail.

Comment: I did found a great Node.js project which allows me to create a web page with a YouTube video player. The video player's time is the same for everybody who's on this web page so everybody can listen to the music at the same time (it's like [plug.dj](https://plug.dj/)). I'd like to extract the audio from this web page and stream it to an Icecast server, so I could have a radio stream with the same music as the web page playing at the same time.